# MongoDB views remain empty

Tags: mongodb, view

I'm new to MongoDB and am trying to create a view on an existing collection `atlassianHost`. However that view unfortunately remains empty when queried.

#### > db.atlassianHost.find({})

```
{ _id: 'XXXXXXXX-156c-3b67-b9d0-a0c975487af6',
  publicKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/eQ83HpM00jQe3XkpLhEFQwbog55OxsbZYxBMeewQuouot0MQCESTMKZa2eRIaHlWVIsAcJc/mrYKyAYz8LmkpipG3X+5eTCQVUQDQ9g2jAC34rXzKSWt7QjKI1ZoDn/OJvmr6UuROhywe/7WScvwIDAQAB',
  sharedSecret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXVJnis2CLx1gpDJfShO7LlYE22O36EzT4P2h/ILAwbrQIijukZSA',
  baseUrl: 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.atlassian.net',
  productType: 'jira',
  description: 'Atlassian JIRA at https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.atlassian.net ',
  addonInstalled: true,
  _class: 'com.atlassian.connect.spring.AtlassianHost' }
```

#### > db.createView("atlassianHostView","atlassianHost",[ {$match: {}}, {$project: { url: "$baseUrl" }} ]);

```
{ ok: 1 }
```

#### > db.atlassianHostView.find({})

```
/* empty result */
```

#### Hints

What I have noticed is that the created view `atlassianHostView` does NOT show the view icon in MongoDB Compass.

[image]

I'm using a local instance of Mongodb 2.6.11 via Docker (https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/mongodb)

Can anyone point a bloody MongoDB newbie into the right direction? - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am embarased to admit that I have used a **5 year old version** of MongoDB:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/mongodb is 5 years old and runs MongoDB 2.6.11
- Nowdays we run MongoDB 4.4.4

After I have switched to a new image the view worked.

#### Bonus

In order for the thread to provide at least some value, here's a fragment of my docker composer file to launch a local Mongodb for my development project environment.

#### > docker-compose-local.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    mongodb-local:
        image: mongo:4.4.4
#        environment:
#          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
#          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
        ports:
          - 27017:27017
        volumes:
          - /srv/docker/mongodb:/data/db
        restart: unless-stopped
```